# c include each other with forward declaration

Tags: c

DecompileTestApplication_Program.h

```
#ifndef _DecompileTestApplication_Program_
#define _DecompileTestApplication_Program_
struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram;
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    //Variables
    int ind;
    int a;
    int b;
    int __refs__;
} DecompileTestApplication_Program;
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Plan( DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram* );
//error: expected ')' before '*' token
#endif
```

DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram.h

```
#ifndef _DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram_
#define _DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram_
struct DecompileTestApplication_Program;
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    //Variables
    DecompileTestApplication_Program* program;
    int __refs__;
} DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram;
#endif
```

This is again my IL (C#\VB compiled code) to C decompiler.
I have tried few methods to do that ,but don't get any successful compilation.
BTW ,I using Dev-Cpp to compile with original C.

Comment: What's your compilation command?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cjx18NrF It's makefile that Dev-Cpp created. I didn't compiled with console ,just clicked compile at Dev-Cpp IDE.

Comment: //error: expected ')' before '*' token. I wrote it up there in the first file.

Comment: Sorry guys ,but i am still didn't resolve that errors.

Answer (score 0):

In C, declaring a structure type with a tag does not declare the bare tag as a type (unlike C++).  You have to do:

```
typedef struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram;
```

And that does not fit on one line on SO without the horizonatal scroll-bar.

Alternatively, you have to prefix the tag with `struct` each time:

```
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Plan(struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram*);
```

---

### Expanded answer

As well as ensuring that the single word is an alias for the `struct` using `typedef`, 
you also have to ensure that there's only one `typedef` for each type.

As a side note, your names for your header guards are intruding on the namespace reserved for the implementation (that means, for the people who write the C compiler).  Don't do that.  Don't use names starting with an underscore in general, and especially not names starting with either two underscores or one underscore and a capital letter.

In context, that means:

#### DecompileTestApplication_Program.h

```
#ifndef DecompileTestApplication_Program_header
#define DecompileTestApplication_Program_header
typedef struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram;
typedef struct DecompileTestApplication_Program DecompileTestApplication_Program;
struct DecompileTestApplication_Program
{
    //Variables
    int ind;
    int a;
    int b;
    int __refs__;  // This is not safe either!
};
// Why is this function declared here and not in the other header?
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Plan(DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram *prog);
#endif
```

#### DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram.h

```
#ifndef DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram_header
#define DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram_header
#include "DecompileTestApplication_Program.h"
struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram
{
    //Variables
    DecompileTestApplication_Program* program;
    int __refs__;  // Dangerous
};
#endif
```

Neither header self-evidently needed `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: error: conflicting types for 'DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram'. This error shows right on the typedef.

Comment: What is Dev-Cpp?  Is that a C++ compiler or a C compiler?  Does the error occur when you include the first file before or after the second (or does it appear both ways)?  You have to ensure there's only one `typedef` for the type, so you may need to rewrite the current `typedef struct /* no tag! */ { ... } LongAndHorribleName;` with the tag and without the `typedef` (and remove the second `LongAndHorribleName` since it becomes a variable name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's not really Dev-Cpp but Dev-C++ and it's a C++ compiler for Windows.

Comment: In dev-cpp you can choose with what to compile to. The errors occur when i include it from the C file. About the LongAndHorribleName ,sorry... It's decompiler to C.

Comment: Regarding name: I understand they're quasi-generated names dictated by external mechanisms beyond your control.  It's just that LongAndHorribleName is about half the length of the other names, so I used that in my comments.  Not strictly fair on you...  Sorry!

Comment: That's not it ,this is just a part of my decompiled code ,I copied the code that might help you understand the problem. @JonathanLeffler np.

Answer (score 0):

This is C, not C++. Declaring/defining a struct doesn't create a new type name. So, either your function declaration in the first file should be

```
void DecompileTestApplication_Program_Plan(struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram);
```

or yous should use a typedef:

```
typedef struct DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram;
```

In this case, you'll have to omit the `typedef` keyword in the second file, just leaving

```
struct XXX.... {
};
```

Comment: error: conflicting types for 'DecompileTestApplication_MyAnotherProgram'. This error shows right on the typedef. (Copy paste from the second answer)

Comment: @Jonathan Lefflee thanks for the edit -- I haven't revised my code *structly* enough...

Comment: @SuperFile also, omit the typedef keyword from the second file.

Comment: Tried ,still errors but 2x less. (Same errors ,conficting types and previous declaring was here)